# Dynamic Jquery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll

I am building a site [here](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philsports/test.html) but having a problem with linking to pages. This site is a one pager site that has a menue and a javascript that triggers it. Not if you visit the link I wanted to link the 3 green boxes to level1,level2,level3 like the main menu. But having a problem on how to do it.

**here is the code for the Top Menu**

```
<div class="navi"> 
<a style="display:none"></a> 
<a id="t1">Level 1</a> 
<a id="t2">Level 2</a> 
<a id="t3">Level 3</a> 
<a id="t4">Online Marketing</a>
 <a id="t5">Social Media</a> 
<a id="t6">Contact us</a> 
<a id="t7" class="noBorder">Français</a> 
</div>
```

**And here is the Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// initialize scrollable and return the programming API
var api = $("#scroll").scrollable({
    items: '#tools',
    size: 1,
    clickable: false

// use the navigator plugin
}).navigator({api: true});


// this callback does the special handling of our "intro page"
api.onStart(function(e, i) {

    // when on the first item: hide the intro
    if (i) {
        $("#intro").fadeOut("slow");

    // otherwise show the intro
    } else {
        $("#intro").fadeIn(1000);
    }

    // toggle activity for the intro thumbnail
    $("#t0").toggleClass("active", i == 0);
});

// a dedicated click event for the intro thumbnail
$("#t0").click(function() {

    // seek to the beginning (the hidden first item)
    $("#scroll").scrollable().begin();

});

</script>
```

What do I change or modify so I could get the 3 green boxes in the Home page to act like level 1, level 2, level 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your green boxes:

```
<h2 class="microsite"><a href="" onclick="javascript:api.seekTo(1); return false;">Microsite Website Package</a></h2>
<h2 class="cms"><a href="" onclick="javascript:api.seekTo(2); return false;">CMS Website Package</a></h2>
<h2 class="transactional"><a href="" onclick="javascript:api.seekTo(3); return false;">E-commerce Website Package</a></h2>
```

note i've removed the **id**'s. you should never have a duplicate id on a page. it may break things.